# How to create a hyperlink to a table?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm trying to add text and a hyperlink to a table. The data I'm referring to does exist. I grabbed this from [Microsoft's text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add).

```vb
Sheets("Ticket Status").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Ticket Status").Cells(j, 10), _
  Address:=Sheets("Leaf").Cells(leafRow, 1), _
  ScreenTip:="", _
  TextToDisplay:=Sheets("Leaf").Cells(leafRow, 2)
```

I get

> Run-Time error "5" Invalid procedure call or argument.

Changing the Anchor from .Cells to .Range("J" & j) did not make any difference.

Every source I looked at has similar VBA.

Comment: Please, edit your question and show us which values have the involved cells.

Comment: `Address:="", SubAddress:="'Leaf'!" & Cells(leafRow, 1).Address()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create Hyperlink

**The 3 Issues**

1. `Address` has to be present.
2. `SubAddress` has to be an `Excel` address.
3. `TextToDisplay` has to be text, i.e. `wsL.Cells(leafRow, 2)` doesn't work.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub addHyperlink()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsT As Worksheet
    Set wsT = wb.Worksheets("Ticket Status")
    Dim wsL As Worksheet
    Set wsL = wb.Worksheets("Leaf")
    
    Dim leafRow As Long
    Dim j As Long
    leafRow = 2
    j = 2
    
    wsT.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=wsT.Cells(j, 10), _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="'" & wsL.Name & "'!A" & leafRow, _
        TextToDisplay:=wsL.Cells(leafRow, 2).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted VBasic2008's answer (and Tim William's) answer as it was pretty close.  I wasn't very clear in my question (as FanDuru alluded to.).

What I found though was the hyperlink addition really didn't like special characters.  But putting the value into a variable it worked good.

```
tempValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Leaf").Cells(leafRow, 1)
tempDisplay = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Leaf").Cells(leafRow, 2)
         
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ticket Status").Hyperlinks.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ticket Status").Cells(j, 10), tempValue, , "Go to " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ticket Status").Cells(j & 5).Value & " LEAF record", tempDisplay
```